# How to use an optimizer within a forward pass in PyTorch

Tags: optimization, pytorch, torch, autograd

I want to use an optimizer within the forward pass of a custom defined Function, but it doesn't work. My code is as follows:

```
class MyFct(Function):

   @staticmethod
   def forward(ctx, *args):
       input, weight, bias = args[0], args[1], args[2]

       y = torch.tensor([[0]], dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True) #initial guess
       loss_fn = lambda y_star: (input + weight - y_star)**2

       learning_rate = 1e-4
       optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([y], lr=learning_rate)
       for t in range(5000):
           y_star = y
           print(y_star)
           loss = loss_fn(y_star)
           if t % 100 == 99:
               print(t, loss.item())
           optimizer.zero_grad()
           loss.backward()
           optimizer.step() 

       return y_star
```

And that's my test inputs:

```
x = torch.tensor([[2]], dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
w = torch.tensor([[2]], dtype=torch.float, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([[6]], dtype=torch.float)

fct= MyFct.apply
y_hat = fct(x, w, None)
```

I always get the **RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn**.

Also, I've tested the optimization outside of the forward and it works, so I guess it's something with the context? According to the documentation "Tensor arguments that track history (i.e., with requires_grad=True) will be converted to ones that don’t track history before the call, and their use will be registered in the graph", see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html. Is this the problem? Is there a way to work around it?

I am new to PyTorch and I wonder what I'm overlooking. Any help and explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8847 , i.e. I need to wrap the oprimization with `with torch.enable_grad():`.

However, I still don't understand why it's necessary to convert the original Tensors to ones that don’t track history in forward().